# If inner HTML = X = display XX in div XXX

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

Im trying to do this.
If div with id javascript has X in inner HTML then insert XX in div with id XXX.

Can someone help me out? Thanks!

```html
<div id="XXX">XX</div>

<div id="javascript"><?php include 'TEST.php'; ?></div>

<script>
window.setInterval(function() {  
    httpGetAsync('TEST.php', function(text) {  
        if (document.getElementById("javascript").innerHTML == "X") { 
document.getElementById("XXX") = "XX";
        } 

    });  
}, 10000);
</script>
```

Comment: In `.innerHTML == X`, the `X` is not defined.  Did you mean for it to be a String (`"X"`)?  Also did you mean to use `.contains()` instead of literal `==`?

Comment: Yes ''X'' i fixed it. I ment == equal to.

Comment: Then please delete this question as it was the result of a typo and is unlikely to be useful to others.

Comment: I fixed the spelling errors. And yes i think it can be usefull to others.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use this

```
document.getElementById("XXX").innerHTML = "XX";
```

Comment: Thanks very usefull maybe i can solve this.